# How do I embed all my python code onto my website, assuming I can't just embed the main file?

Tags: python, html, game-development, publish

I have python code for a game called The maze, which has several folders, subfolders, and files. The files range from .py files to .png files. I can run this game comfortably on my IDE through my main file. However, I can't figure out how to present the game to a user through my website. I am aware I should embed the game onto my website using HTML, but how do I go about it? Should I embed only the main file? Should I embed the entire repository? Should I use a compiled file? Let me know if there are any tricks or tools to achieve this. All the said folders and files are uploaded in a github repository. Kindly help.

Comment: Are you looking to have the users browser run your python game directly, or are you looking to offer a download of your python game that the user would then run locally?

Comment: @JonSG My intention is to get them to run the game directly from the browser. Through a link probably, depending on the suggestions ill get.

Comment: You can check out the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181600/is-it-possible-to-run-game-made-with-pygame-on-browser-using-pyscript